# Reactjs: update state not show current value on next line

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my code:

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState("1");

const updateData = () => {
    setAmount("2");
    console.log(address);
}
```

After `updateData`, why printed `1`? I changed it to `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(address)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [address])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "address" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use await? `await setAddress("2");` or `setTimeOut`?

Comment: Just FYI setting state in React isn't anything at all like an async function. The `setState` function is complete synchronous. It enqueues an update to be processed later. Think of it more like a request to update state.

Comment: @ali No, `setAmount` isn't an `async` function nor does it return a Promise, so there's nothing to `await` nor will any amount of `setTimeout` in the callback function scope change the value of `address` as it's a Javascript closure over the `address` value when the function was invoked.